# Candlestick graph in tkinter canvas/frame

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas, candlestick-chart

I am trying to create a candlestick chart into tkinter. I have main window top, and I am creating a frame (graph_frame) at specific location. After click of a button, I want to place my candlestick chart into that frame. I am running followed code, but instead of placing chart into frame, the chart gets displayed in jupyter notebook output. I want to place this chart into my tkinter window and the specific canvas frame I created.

```
from tkinter import * 
#import Pmw
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
from datetime import date
from io import StringIO
import datetime 
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import pandas as pd
import arrow
import datetime
import sys
import json
import yfinance as yf
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import quandl as ql
from matplotlib import dates
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.dates as mpdates

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg,NavigationToolbar2Tk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import mplfinance as mpf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mpl_dates


top = tk.Tk()   
top.title("NASDAR Stock price range prediction system")
top.geometry("1350x840")


graph_frame = tk.Frame(top, height=350, width=500)

graph_frame.place(x=700,y=250) 
figure = plt.Figure(figsize=(12,8), dpi=50)
ax = figure.add_subplot(111)


df = yf.download('ba', period='500d', interval='1d')

df = df.tail(50)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
 
# apply map function
df['Date'] = df['Date'].map(mpdates.date2num)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, graph_frame)
 
# plotting the data
candlestick_ohlc(ax, df.values, width = 0.6,colorup = 'green', colordown = 'red', alpha = 0.8)
ohlc = df.loc[:, ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']]
ohlc['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ohlc['Date'])
ohlc['Date'] = ohlc['Date'].apply(mpl_dates.date2num)
ohlc = ohlc.astype(float)


ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Price')

# Formatting Date
date_format = mpl_dates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_format)



ax.set_title('Candlestick chart')
```

Comment: What have you done so far to try to solve the problem?   What happens when you run it outside of jupyter notebook (and outside of any ide)?  Does it work then, or not?  Have you tried running `plt.ioff()` at the top of your notebook?   And/or have you tried running `%matplotlib tkagg` at the top of your notebook?  Please list everything you have tried, and the specific result for each.

Comment: I did try both of the options you mentioned, and also tried various other website solutions. But so far no luck. I am NOT hardcore python developer, just working on PoC. So, all i need is how can I add candlestick chart only ( please not that I can add line graphs, scatter graphs very easily in the specific frames :) ).  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Followed code worked and I am able to generate graphs into my specific frame in tkinter. graph_frame has been declared in the beginning in main function.

````
figure = plt.Figure(figsize=(3,4), dpi=100)

#data = yf.download(symbol, period='500d', interval='1d')

data = yf.download('ba', period='500d', interval='1d')
df = convert_to_dataframe_daily(data)
#df = return_data_frame()
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['SMA5'] = df['Close'].rolling(5).mean()
df = df.tail(15)

     
    # apply map function
df['Date'] = df['Date'].map(mpdates.date2num)


figure, ax = plt.subplots()

fig = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, graph_frame)


ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Price')

    #fig.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)
fig.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
 
        # plotting the data
candlestick_ohlc(ax, df.values, width = 0.6,colorup = 'green', colordown = 'red', alpha = 0.8)
ohlc = df.loc[:, ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']]
#ohlc['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ohlc['Date'])
#ohlc['Date'] = ohlc['Date'].apply(mpl_dates.date2num)
#ohlc = ohlc.astype(float)
print(ohlc.tail(10))


    #fig.suptitle('Daily Candlestick Chart of NIFTY50')

    # Formatting Date
date_format = mpl_dates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_format)

ax.plot(df['Date'], df['EMA21'], color='green', label='EMA 21', linewidth=0.5)

ax.plot(df['Date'], df['EMA8'], color='blue', label='EMA 8', linewidth=0.5)

ax.plot(df['Date'], df['SMA200'], color='darkorange', label='SMA 200', linewidth=1.5)

    
ax.grid(True)

ax.set_title('Candlesticks with moving averages')
    

    
    ```
````